# How to connect to the remote server for express checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Everything is working absolutely fine in development here on my local machine.   When I migrate the code to the production server at our hosting site and remain in Sandbox mode I get an error.

```
Exception in HttpConnection Execute: Invalid HTTP response Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I've debugged with traces to this spot in the code:

```
    Dim setECResponse As SetExpressCheckoutResponseType = service.SetExpressCheckout(wrapper)
```

Our Web.Config has the following Entries:

```
  <add key="PAYPAL_REDIRECT_URL" value="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&amp;cmd="/>
  <add key="E_HOSTING_ENDPOINT" value="http://localhost"/>
  <add key="PAYPAL_API_MODE" value="sandbox" />
  <add key="PAYPAL_API_USERNAME" value="babrams-facilitator_api1.commuter.net" />
  <add key="PAYPAL_API_PASSWORD" value="1395365656" />
  <add key="PAYPAL_API_SIGNATURE" value="A78sCS0nUCkkjVsrxFQEygQ8fAp4ACIRrk.iJ6zw7-HJiwaeO0k28aIB" />
```

We tried changing the E_HOSTING_ENDPOINT to our website domain, but we get the same error.  I also tried testing these URLS from a html page on the production server and they work fine, so I don't think this is a firewall issue or network connectivity at fault.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-4WB48589UH622552B
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

The project works fine in development.  It is only in production that it does not work.

Any insight as to what we should look for, or how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer was that the Hosting Company has installed a Microsoft patch that removed the "Ciphers" from their server, which caused the PayPal DLL to be rendered incapable of performing it's functions normally. They replaced the ciphers and rebooted. Everything worked after that.  The hosting company declined to let me know which MS patch caused the issue, so I can not report on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to ensure CURL is enabled on your production server?

Comment: Thanks.  The hosting company responded that they do not support cURL on their windows servers for some reason.  I sent that to PayPal, and they replied that cURL is supported on Windows and sent a link to github to educate the Arvixe support staff as to how.

Comment: Hi Andrew - I'm still in the same situation and don't have an answer yet.  I'm wondering about your reply... are you suggesting that curl must be enabled on the production server for PayPal to work with the PayPalMerchantSDK.dll using ASP.Net?

Comment: If your host doesn't provide basic features and you can't mimic your own test server because of it I would recommend a different host.  That said, it's possible they provide some other method similar to cURL to send HTTP POST requests to servers.  Really that's all you're doing.  I'm just not familiar with .NET and IIS so I really can't give you much detail on that.  Try Googling stuff about sending HTTP POST requests with .NET and see where that takes you.  Really, though, a different host might be the quickest and easiest thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Andrew.  Up until this incident I've found my hosting company to be very responsive.  This was a pretty poor show on their part.  They simply declined to dig into the issue and assumed it was PayPal's fault.  Paypal of course did the same.  IN the end the answer was that the Hosting Company has installed a Microsoft patch that removed the "Ciphers" from their server, which caused the PayPal DLL to be rendered incapable of performing it's functions normally.  They replaced the ciphers and rebooted.  Everything worked after that.  Total turnaround time?  5 months.

Comment: Yeah, that sucks. Glad you got it worked out, though.